Returning Entity Results with Includes from Web Api
I'm fairly new to Entity Framework Core.
I have a data structure like this:
Books contain many Chapters.
Chapters contain many PageNotes.
My entity query in my API controller is like this, and through debugging it I can see it is finding the correct results.
ServiceResponse<List<Book>> response = new ServiceResponse<List<Book>>();

List<Book> Books = await _context.Books.Include(x => x.Chapters).ThenInclude(x => x.PageNotes).ToListAsync();

response.Data = Books;
response.Success = true;
response.Message = "List of All Books Provided";

return Ok(response);

The issue is that I am getting the following exception in my controller, when it tries to return the data.
System.InvalidOperationException: The exception handler configured on ExceptionHandlerOptions produced a 404 status response. This InvalidOperationException containing the original exception was thrown since this is often due to a misconfigured ExceptionHandlingPath. If the exception handler is expected to return 404 status responses then set AllowStatusCode404Response to true.
---> System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles. Path: $.Data.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Book.Chapters.Id.

Any advice appreciated!
Incase it is relevant, here are my database classes. It's my first time creating such a complex structure so the issue may be there?
public class MyBooksTable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    
    public ICollection<UserBook> UserBooks { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public AppUser User { get; set; }
}

public class UserBook
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public string Id { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("MyBooksTableId")]
    public string MyBooksTableId { get; set; }
    public MyBooksTable MyBooksTable { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("BooksId")]
    public string BooksId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }


    public DateTime BookDateOfPurchase { get; set; } = DateTime.MinValue;

}


public class Book
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();


    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public decimal Price { get; set; } = decimal.Zero;


    public ICollection<Chapter> Chapters { get; set; } = new List<Chapter>();

    public ICollection<UserBook>? UserBooks { get; set; }

}

public class Chapter
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<PageNote>? PageNotes { get; set; } = new List<Note>();


    [ForeignKey("BookId")]
    public string BookId { get; set; }
    public Book Book { get; set; }
}

public class PageNote
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;


    [ForeignKey("ChapterId")]
    public string ChapterId { get; set; }
    public Chapter Chapter { get; set; }

}


Looks like error is due to large amount of data being returned.  It may be an exception due to Out-Of-Memory.  The code is trying to json serialize the return data and getting a failure.  Could be the data is null.  The error message may be misleading.

Use AsNoTracking or better use DTO clasess and project everything via Select. It is bad idea to expose Model via API.

The error you face, System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected, which is usually caused by your nested object structure referring back to the same instance and creating a loop. In your case, this can occur because your entities (Book, Chapter, and PageNote) are referred to from each other in such a way that, when the data is serialized to JSON, it turns out to try to serialize an infinite chain of references loop.
To resolve this, you have a couple of options:

Use ReferenceHandler.Preserve in your JSON serialization settings: This way, the serializer will be in a position to deal with the circular references by preserving the reference table. You can set this in your Startup.cs or Program.cs depending on which .NET Core version you are using. Here's how you would normally set it up in Startup.cs:

services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(x =>
    x.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);

It tells the JSON serializer to track references and not let it get into a loop if a circular reference is encountered.

Limit the depth of your query: Another way to do it is not to load the whole object graph within the query. You can later change it so that only levels of relevant data are brought in, but for most cases—especially in more complex domain models—this will be needed.

Use DTOs (Data Transfer Objects): Map the entity objects into the simpler, flat DTOs that don't have circular references. This is generally considered good practice, as you can exactly format your data as it will be needed by the client, without disclosing the structure of your database or adding unnecessary data that the client does not require.

Define DTOs




public class BookDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public List<ChapterDTO> Chapters { get; set; }
}

public class ChapterDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<PageNoteDTO> PageNotes { get; set; }
}

public class PageNoteDTO
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}


Configure AutoMapper


public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Book, BookDTO>();
        CreateMap<Chapter, ChapterDTO>();
        CreateMap<PageNote, PageNoteDTO>();
    }
}


Use AutoMapper in your service


public async Task<ServiceResponse<List<BookDTO>>> GetBooksAsync()
{
    var response = new ServiceResponse<List<BookDTO>>();
    
    var books = await _context.Books
        .Include(x => x.Chapters)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.PageNotes)
        .ToListAsync();

    // Map the book entities to book DTOs
    var bookDTOs = _mapper.Map<List<BookDTO>>(books);

    response.Data = bookDTOs;
    response.Success = true;
    response.Message = "List of All Books Provided";

    return response;
}

If, for example, your API consumers of your API do not have a mandate to know the full details for each Chapter and PageNote for a Book, then your BookDTO may include just a list of chapter titles, or counts and not full Chapter objects.
Considering the current code and structure applied, it may be that the very first way is with ReferenceHandler.Preserve, which works out the most. Further on, using DTOs may provide a solution more scalable and maintainable, especially since your application is going to grow and change over time.

Thanks for the info. I had stumbled upon the Json reference handler stuff and it worked, but I've never had to return json in my response DTO before. It doesn't really work. it's like I am putting the data into Json, then trying to get it back as an object to add it to my response DTO.

As for just using DTOs, I think this is probably the right answer. Get Listbooks using entity and then, maybe using Automapper, map to a BookDTO and return that as part of my response DTO.

Yes, using DTOs and AutoMapper is a best practice in API development. It separates internal data models from external ones, resolves serialization issues, and provides a more secure and maintainable architecture. I updated my answers to reflect this.

That answer is fantastic! I started working on it myself this morning and got nearly the same result, but looks like my automapper config was slightly wrong. Thanks for the hard work my friend!

Thank you for your kind feedback, it’s been a pleasure. I'm glad that helped you and hear you've achieved similar results.
